# When the power goes off, a line must be grounded - how?

Tags: power-supply, fail-safe

I need a line to be grounded as power to a board is failing. Complicating the issue is the fact that this line is critical to circuit operation and cannot tolerate even nanoVolts of additional noise when working properly. Typical frequencies are less than 1kHz, the voltage can be up to +/-10V driven from a 10K output impedance

It's the +/- input to a highly sensitive analog PID loop. When the input is exactly 0V it thinks everything is fine and perfect. As the power fails, it goes mad and swings wildly and unpredictably. By grounding that input the PID will think all is well even as it dies.

The ugly mechanical way to do it is use a normally closed mechanical relay that is held open by the PSU. When the latter fails the closed relay shorts the line to analog ground before the power to everything else drops below the working voltage.

Under normal working conditions nothing is connected to the input line from this relay (except a short stub of track)

Is there a way to do it using non-mechanical means?

Comment: This is so lacking detail it's impossible to answer. Can you add a lot more detail by improving the question text (not just dumping more under EDIT:).

Comment: You might be able to find a depletion mode FET that does a similar job to the relay.

Comment: 1 ohm will produce 4 nV of Johnson noise at a bandwidth of 1 kHz at 20 degC. The induced voltage perturbations from normal movement might be likely to exceed 1 nV in the earths magnetic field. Triboelectric effects might be many times this value.

Comment: @TonyM It's the +/- input to a highly sensitive PID loop. When the input is exactly 0V it thinks everything is fine and perfect. As the power fails, it goes mad and swings wildly and unpredictably. By grounding that input the PID will think all is well even as it dies.

Comment: @Andyaka True, but this is for a balance that can measure down into the nanograms. Every possible source of noise has been minimized, at significant cost. I don't want to add yet more.

Comment: TonyM has the right of this.  We cannot help without context or circuit. Your comments need to be added to the question.

Comment: Is the goal to simply _bring_ the circuit to ground, or to keep it grounded indefinitely? If the goal is only to _bring_ the circuit to ground, you could use a temporary power supply, such as a battery or large capacitor, to drive a mosfet switch triggered by low voltage on your power supply. (The temporary supply would only power the switch, not your circuit). Also, what is wrong with a relay? Why is it an "ugly" solution?

Comment: You need to specify maximum working peak to peak input voltage expected. Maximum input current expected (presumably low). Is there a DC bias on the input or is it AC coupled ?

Comment: Thanks, @StainlessSteelRat. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. This question appears to be waiting for comment discussion, and unfortunately it's being rewarded with discussion by posters here. Instead, the question should be considerably improved. Voting to close for that reason.

Comment: Reed relay jumps to mind, ugly though it may be; JFET second best (it will contribute Johnson noise when ON, but little or none during operation (OFF). Process 58 with relatively low Ron may be worth a look.

Comment: Maybe stupid but... what about putting a resistor from the input to ground?

Comment: Perhaps determining what type of "short" your input can tolerate. No device semiconductor or mechanical will give you a "perfect" 0Ω short. If your input can tolerate up to say 1 - 2 Ω short without a problem, your cheapest and consistent option will still be a depletion-type MOSFET, less than $0,50, and some with 100V Drain-Source breakdown, plenty of margin for your ±10 input signal. Can you test to see what is maximum resistance on input that does not cause you problems, and then choose a MOSFET with a lower one, say x5 margin, for your working version ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use normally closed optorelays with MOSFET output. There are parts with various On-resistance vs. Off-capacitance so you can choose according to your needs.

Costs only about 1€ and to keep them open, you just need to run something like 2 mA through their ~1.2V Infrared LED, which will be easy with any likely power rail.

The advantage vs. non-isolated depletion FET is that you have very little capacitance between the potentially noisy digital off-signal and the channel. Also, they are bidirectionally blocking when off.

This will add no noise to your signal chain because it is a parallel shunt.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do it using non-mechanical means?

I don't think so.

A electromechanical relay is what an electronics engineer would use.

If you use an electronic switch, like a depletion MOSFET for example, the problem you face is that the MOSFET is current limited and you'll never have a real GROUND reference.

---

A depletion MOSFET could work fine if you, for example, need a GROUND signal that is read by an external board through a weak pull-up resistor. In this case infact the current injected in the MOSFET is really small.

---

A depletion MOSFET is a device that has an Ohmic channel between the drain and the source when Vgs = 0.